# Map image url with querystring to MVC3 Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've had a look around and am at a bit of a loss for what I thought would be such a simple problem.

I am using MV3/IIS7 and I am trying to map the url:

```
/SomeFolder/SomeImage.gif?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z
```

to the Action:

```
/SomeController/SomeAction?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z
```

but am not quite getting it. Any Tips?

Comment: Where is the gif coming from?  You can return an image from an action without having any sort of extension on it.

Comment: There is no physical image file, the action is returning the image a byte[] (a simple 1x1 transparent gif). I just don't want to refer to the image as <img src="/SomeController/SomeAction?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z" /> I want to refer to it as <img src="/SomeFolder/SomeImage.gif?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a route in Global.asax.cs like this,

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "",
    "SomeFolder/SomeImage.gif",
    new { controller = "SomeController", Action = "SomeAction" }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. (however I did have to move it above the "Default" MapRoute for it to work) :)

Comment: Yes you have write this route above the default one.